# Apache Proxy to show another Website

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I need to proxy the URL **http://de.domain.com/article1/foobar/** to **http://de.foobar.domain.com/article1/**.

How can I do this within getting and setting the subdomain language part?

Examples:

```
http://de.domain.com/article1/foobar/ => http://de.foobar.domain.com/article1/
http://dk.domain.com/article1/foobar/ => http://dk.foobar.domain.com/article1/
http://en.domain.com/article1/foobar/ => http://en.foobar.domain.com/article1/
http://el.domain.com/article1/foobar/ => http://el.foobar.domain.com/article1/
```

I heard this is not possible only with mod_proxy and I have to use mod_rewrite for this. But I don't know how.
Maybe someone can post an example?

Redirecting is no option.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) http://%1.$2.domain.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/foobar/$  /$1
```

I have tested it using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

Comment: This does output the same URL. If I call http://de.domain.com/article1/foobar/ the Apache proxy should make a call on http://de.foobar.domain.com/article1/

Comment: @StinsonMaster I tested it again and it worked. Can you please check again?

Comment: The website I linked in this post http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ sometimes seems to output the same url. Maybe you can check on your server.

Comment: I tried a little on my own. I got a good result with this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) http://%1.$2.domain.com/$1 [L,R]` It's not working now, but the output url on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ is correct.

Comment: Okay, I will try your config on my server.

Comment: No, doesn't work on my server too.

Comment: My solution is working now (had to remove the RewriteBase). But it makes a redirect because of [L,R]. I tried to use [P] for Proxy, but then he is redirecting me from `http://de.domain.com/article1/foobar/` to `http://de.domain.com/article1/` Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, I think the redirect is because of other rules. I created another topic for this.